# Add-Member of type DirectoryInfo

Tags: powershell

I'm new in powershell.
I need to create a member of type DirectoryInfo. I tried this but don't work:

```
$PathTFS = New-Object System.Object 

$PathTFS | Add-Member -type Property -name TEST1 -value  New-Object System.IO.DirectoryInfo "C:\TEST\TEST1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
$dir = (get-item C:\windows)
$object = New-Object PsObject @{
    Dir = $dir
}
$object.Dir
```

Comment: in this example the $dir.Test is of type String. $dir.Test must be a DirectoryInfo.

Comment: @wallybh I noticed that. I updated it now it should do what you're looking for.